# Which key is able going out to the shell for a while installing FreeBSD?

Tags: installation, freebsd

I want to install FreeBSD Dual Boot with window 7.

Before, I saw a YouTube clip about installation FreeBSD Dual boot.

Above `7:35` min, he suddenly go out to interrupt mode and using shell.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2ZZ6p01410

Which key able that function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like he switched to a virtual console by typing:

<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

You could read more about it here: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/consoles.html

Or also could be that the video don't show the last screen in where it ask for open a shell, check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PB4Os2sYoUY minute 11:04 to understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank for your answer